# how to convert $-3x^2 + 3x + 6$ to vertex form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I convert this standard from problem to vertex form

$y = 3x^2 + 3x + 6$

I really do not understand!

Comment: Your language is unclear. Could you clarify what "standard form" and "vertex form" are? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: the standard form is y = ax^2 + bx + c                           the vertex form is y - k = a(x -h)^2                             I have tried to do the steps, but it is really confusing.

Comment: If I could get a step by step instructions that would help me to do this one and the others also.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$-3x^2+3x+6=-3(x^2-x-2)=-3\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac94\right)$$

You may also want to write

$$-3x^2+3x+6=-3(x-2)(x+1)$$

Added due to OP's confussion:

Wo we already have

$$y=-3\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac94\right)=-3\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac{27}4\implies$$

$$y-\frac{27}4=-3\left(x-\frac12\right)^2$$